Newer Coworkers have a better office
I have recently started a job within the past 6-7 months. When I started, there were five open offices that were available. My team assigned me into an office and it is in really bad shape. The desk is falling apart at the legs. The legs are bent. The floor is in really bad shape with tiles peeling up. The computer is the most outdated out of any of the offices of my coworkers and the other “open” offices.
But I just accepted it and didn’t really care. There have now been 2 more new hires doing my exact job that have been put into the ‘better’ offices. I have put in maintenance requests for the desk and floors, but they say there’s nothing that can be done because each desk has an assigned office it goes with. I just can’t help but feel  that I was hired first yet given the worst office available when there were more options. My husband claims that the placement may be intentional/my supervisor may not see my staying very long?
Also, I know this sounds superficial. I am happy I have a job, and so far I enjoy the job. Just wonder what others opinions are.

@Guest1 Frame the maintenance requests as possible safety issues. "I am concerned that I or someone might trip over the peeling tiles." and "The legs on the desk are making it less and less stable, I am concerned that it might colapse on me." That ought to kick in their risk detector.

The worst office is still better than the best cube. In 35+ years I never had an office until I started working from home.

“But I just accepted it and didn’t really care.” But now you do? That is called “envy” and isn’t a great look.

You were assigned an office that was available. So were they.
The thing to complain about is that maintenance still hasn't gotten around to repairing yours. You did talk to your manager and submit requests for that, right? Or for a move to another office when it became available? Squeaky wheel and all that; if you don't complain, management assumes you are content.

The most likely explanation is that you've simply been assigned an office arbitrarily as far as the interior condition is concerned.
It's very unlikely that managers approached the question of how to allocate, by asking themselves which are the offices in best condition to assign to the next employee. They are more likely to have allocated on considerations like the tradition of which employees go in which room, or where the last occupant of your role was located, or by physical proximity to your immediate manager.
The next most likely explanation is that offices have been assigned in a specific order, but from worst to best, reserving the better offices free in case they were needed to accommodate a higher status of employee. The fact that they have now been filled by those in your same role, may be simply because there is no alternative space left, and so the better offices cannot be reserved from those in your role any longer.
It wouldn't be common to seek to rearrange existing staff. Also, generally speaking, a 6 month head start is not generally seen as a substantial form of seniority.
I don't follow your husband's logic that you might be seen as "not staying very long". You were assigned the poor office from day one, and the company has hired additional people in your role, so there is no evidence here of either a broader redundancy situation or that you have been singled out personally for poorer treatment.

It is your choice.  You accepted it and said you were happy with and didn't care.
If it bothers you, then talk to your manager about it.  But if it now makes you unhappy, then look for another job.  Maybe this time, ask where you would be sitting.
